# Yii2: Redirect to another page index inside a tab

Tags: php, yii, tabs, yii2

I trying to redirect to another index page inside the tab.

```
  <?php 
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use kartik\tabs\TabsX;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use frontend\models\OpStates;
use frontend\models\OpContact;
use frontend\models\OpCountries;
use frontend\models\OpClient;
use frontend\models\OpUnit;
use frontend\models\OpMaintenanceCharges;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;


$this->title = 'Change Profile';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>

<div class="site-changedetails">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'changedetails-form',]); ?>
  <?= TabsX::widget([
        'position' => TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
        'align' => TabsX::ALIGN_LEFT,
        'items' => [
            [
                'label'=>'Client Details',
                'content'=>
                        '<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, "client_code")->textInput(["maxlength" => true]).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                               $form->field($model, "contact_id")->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpContact::find()->all(),'id','code')).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                              $form->field($model, "unit_id")->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpUnit::find()->all(),'id','code')).' 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'country_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpCountries::find()->all(),'id','name'),
                                    [
                                        'prompt' => 'Select Country',
                                         'onchange' => '
                                                            $.post("index.php?r=op-states/lists&id='.'" + $(this).val(), function(data){
                                                                    $("select#opclient-states_id").html(data);
                                                            });' 
                                    ]).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'states_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpStates::find()->all(),'id','state_name'),
                                            [
                                                'prompt' => 'Select States',

                                            ]).'
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]).'
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">'.
                                 $form->field($model, 'postcode')->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        '
            ],

            [
                'label'=>'Client Details 2',
                'content'=>
                     '  <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, "charge_interest")->dropDownList(['Yes'=>'Yes','No'=>'No']).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'interest_effective_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [

                                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                                'autoclose'=>true,
                                                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                                 'todayHighlight' => true,
                                                'todayBtn' => true,
                                            ]
                                        ]).'
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "charge_reminder")->dropDownList(['Yes'=>'Yes','No'=>'No']).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "external_debtor_code")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address1")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address2")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address3")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address4")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    '
            ],

            [

                'label'=>'Maintenance Charges',

                'content'=> Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(['//op-maintenance-charges/index'])),

            ],
        ]
    ]); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Save',['class'=>'pull-right btn btn-primary','style'=>'width:70px; height:40px;','name'=>'button1']) ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

But then it shows the error **Object of class yii\web\Response could not be converted to string**. How should I type it? Or is there any error in my code? Your help appreciated. Thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use label for this

```
'label'=>'<a href="'. Url::to(['//op-maintenance-charges/index']) . '">Maintenance Charges</a>',
```